# GridView convert to ListView on button Tap

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I have a UICollectionView with JSON data. I want to convert the GridView to List view when i tap on button. How to do that?

Comment: Add some detail and code related to your issue, so someone can help.

Comment: http://zappdesigntemplates.com/collectionview-flow-layout-from-grid-to-list-layout/#disqus_thread

Comment: this is in swift...i want same thing in objective c

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. set size here.

Comment: where should i have to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change to list like view then just set the cell width to screen width or your collection view width
update its value while switching from grid to list view as follows,

Declare a variable in your view controller as follows

```
//Property to maintain cell size
@property CGFloat *listCellSize;

//Action methods
- (IBAction)listViewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.listCellSize = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    [self.collecttionView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)gridViewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.listCellSize = self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 3;
    [self.collecttionView reloadData];
}

//CollectionView datasource method
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(self.listCellSize, 100);
    return cellSize;
}
```